# Azure DevOps Deployment on Apache web server

Tags: php, apache, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

I need to know how can I deploy my php application on apache webserver which is running on Ubuntu VM in Azure.

I am trying to setup a CI/CD process for my app on server and I do not understand what steps would I need to configure in my CI/CD.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not able to find any guide on this will appreciate if any one can help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use case is specific as well as any other use case for a custom CI/CD solution. But fear not!

Microsoft Azure documentation is extensive on the subject.
Please refer to the specific guide for your case of Azure VM :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/cicd-for-azure-vms and come back with any specific question you might have.

Comment: My specific question here is, that for some servers or paas services azure devops offer tasks that can be used for CD, but for deploying to Apache2 server there is no task. How would I perform deployment in this case with out their being any task specific for Apache deployment.

Comment: oh, I see. If no Task is there, best bet is with some https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml  or something similar (python, ansible... you name it). Keep in mind it will be a custom solution though.